# java fx event handling on line

Tags: events, line, javafx-2

I found a very interesting article about JavFx2 and about this one

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/handlers.htm

I would like to know how to do for creating an object that extends features of a line, so to insert a manage of events.

In example, single left mouse click, double left mouse click on a drawn line, or press canc key from keybooard while mouse is hover the line (line selected), or left mouse click outside the line?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same problem.

I want to have a 'Drawing Panel' where I can place helper lines which are draggable.
You can attach a MouseHandler via 'setOnMousePressed' and 'setOnMouseDragged' to get such behaviour.

But the big problem is, that the lines dimension is so small that you have to be lucky to hit it with the mouse.

Thats why I implemented it the other way around.
I attach a mouse handler to the drawing panel and on every mouse click i check if the mouse cusor is in the near of any of the helper lines.
This gives me the oportunity to add a little tolerance, so the lines can be clicked and dragged.

I cannot say if the is the most efficient way and will be happy if someone else comes up with a better idea.

> **Edit:**
> Meanwhile I wrote a little test and found out that my first idea wasn't that good.
>
> My second idea was to wrap the line in a Pane and center it's y-coordinate (for vertical lines) inside that pane.
> On that pane I set the mouse handlers. And since i made the pane having a preferred height of 5 pixels, there's now enough tolerance for the mouse cursor to catch that line.
>
> If any one is interested in the idea, I can post a little example code therefore.

Greetings, -chris-

Answer (score 0):

This is a recurring problem when using JavaFX. Currently, I am overlaying all thin visuals with invisible thick counterparts and register event listeners on the thick visuals.

For example, you have a connection consisting of multiple line segments:

```
// construct invisible fat lines for selection
selectionLines.getChildren().clear();
for (Node child : connection.getChildren()) {
    Line line = (Line) child;
    Line selLine = new Line(line.getStartX(), line.getStartY(), line.getEndX(), line.getEndY());
    selLine.setLayoutX(line.getLayoutX());
    selLine.setLayoutY(line.getLayoutY());
    selLine.setStrokeWidth(SELECTION_LINE_WIDTH);
    selLine.setStroke(INVISIBLE);
    selectionLines.getChildren().add(selLine);
}
connection.getChildren().add(selectionLines);
```